# Rpi SPI nRF24L01+ 2.4GHz Transceiver Module Send Message to Arduino Problem

Tags: arduino, nrf24l01

I have recently bought two nRF24L01+ radio chips for communication between my Raspberry Pi and Arduino.
I will be solely using this from Raspberry towards Arduino.
The tutorial I followed:
https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/wireless-rf-communication-between-arduino-and-raspberry-pi-using-nrf24l01

**My problem is**: I don't receive anything. The Raspberry seems to send everything properly (i.e. "H", "i", "0", ... etc)
Serial output is listed below.
Can someone please help me?

The code I am using for Raspberry:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import spidev
from lib_nrf24 import NRF24

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pipes = [[0xE0, 0xE0, 0xF1, 0xF1, 0xE0], [0xF1, 0xF1, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE0]]

radio = NRF24(GPIO, spidev.SpiDev())
radio.begin(0,25)

radio.setPayloadSize(8)
radio.setChannel(0x76)
radio.setDataRate(NRF24.BR_1MBPS)
radio.setPALevel(NRF24.PA_MIN)

radio.setAutoAck(True)
radio.enableDynamicPayloads()
radio.enableAckPayload()

radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0])
radio.printDetails()

sendMessage = list(" Hi")
while len(sendMessage) < 8:
    sendMessage.append(0)

while True:
    start = time.time()
    radio.write(sendMessage)
    print("Sent the message: {}".format(sendMessage))
    radio.startListening()

    while not radio.available(0):
        time.sleep(1/100)
        if time.time() - start > 2:
            print("Timed out.")
            break

    radio.stopListening()
    time.sleep(3)
```

The code for my Arduino:

```
#include<SPI.h>                   // spi library for connecting nrf
#include<RF24.h>                  // nrf library

RF24 radio(9, 10) ;  // ce, csn pins    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600) ;     // start serial monitor baud rate
  Serial.println("Starting.. Setting Up.. Radio on..") ; // debug message
  radio.begin();        // start radio at ce csn pin 9 and 10
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN) ;   // set power level
  radio.setChannel(0x76) ;            // set chanel at 76
  const uint64_t pipe = 0xE0E0F1F1E0LL ;    // pipe address same as sender i.e. raspberry pi
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipe) ;        // start reading pipe 
  radio.enableDynamicPayloads() ;
  radio.powerUp() ;          
}

void loop() {

  radio.startListening() ;        // start listening forever
  char receivedMessage[8] = {0} ;   // set incmng message for 32 bytes
  if (radio.available()) {       // check if message is coming
    radio.read(receivedMessage, sizeof(receivedMessage));    // read the message and save
    Serial.println(receivedMessage) ;    // print message on serial monitor 
    Serial.println("Turning off the radio.") ;   // print message on serial monitor
    radio.stopListening() ;   // stop listening radio
    String stringMessage(receivedMessage) ;     // change char to string
    delay(1000);    // delay of 1 second 
    Serial.print(stringMessage);   // print received mesage
  }
  delay(10);
}
```

Output: just a loop of

```
Turning off the radio.

Turning off the radio.

Turning off the radio.
```

I have checked my wiring three times over...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103645/discussion-on-question-by-stevencellist-rpi-spi-nrf24l01-2-4ghz-transceiver-mod).

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my issues with Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and Raspberry Pi 4
In lib_nrf24.py in function:

def begin(self, csn_pin ... after self.spidev.openadd:

self.spidev.max_speed_hz = 4000000

Did you find out an other solution?