# Control SPI Wirelessly

Tags: gpio, wireless, spi

I would like to control a [WaveShare e-Ink display](https://www.waveshare.com/7.5inch-e-Paper-HAT.htm) wirelessly. I have lots of experience working with this type of device over SPI using the GPIO boards and the WaveShare python libraries.

I'd like to see if I can do something similar using a wireless module.

I've read about XBee, ZigBee, looked at at least half a dozen different AdaFruit development boards, but I'm a little bit lost. Any suggestions as to modules that can provide some of this functionality would be greatly appreciated.

The WaveShare e-Ink display uses the following pinouts.

```
|Pin   | SPI                                                       | 
|------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
| VCC  | 3.3V                                                      |
| GND  | GND                                                       |
| DIN  | SPI MOSI                                                  |
| CLK  | SPI SCK                                                   |
| CS   | SPI Chip Select (low active)                              |
| DC   | Data/Command control pin (High for data, low for command) |
| RST  | External reset pin (low for reset)                        |
| BUSY | Busy state (low for busy)                                 |
```

Comment: Try SPI 2.4GHz nRF24, it is better than 2.4GHz XBee and ZigBee: (1) Rpi SPI nRF24L01+ 2.4GHz Transceiver Module Send Message to Arduino Problem
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107608/rpi-spi-nrf24l01-2-4ghz-transceiver-module-send-message-to-arduino-problem

(2) Rpi SPI nRF24L01+ 2.4GHz Transceiver Module Discussion
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103645/discussion-on-question-by-stevencellist-rpi-spi-nrf24l01-2-4ghz-transceiver-mod. Cheers.

Comment: I can't see any relevance to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: RaspBee might be more newbie friendly, but more than 10 times more expensive: https://gzhls.at/blob/ldb/9/8/e/b/c935cac12f9a2115d11cc17ce826c4b388f7.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Get a second RPi connected to the display: that will be your "wireless" part. You can remotely access a display using X server protocol. This is typically done from an SSH session (see `ssh -Y`) or a reverse SSH tunnel, which will handle obscure X authentication mechanisms for you.

If you want to have control on SPI level, write your own protocol which allows sending individual SPI transactions. Note that it will be much slower, so such a display will likely be useless as a general-purpose screen.

Comment: I would specifically like to drive the e-paper display without a wired connection to a pi. The refresh rate of the e-paper is on the order of 5-8 seconds per refresh, so speed is hardly any issue as long as the magnitude remains the same.

Comment: @AaronCiuffo SPI is a wired interface, so you'll have to connect that display to something. Why can't that something be a Pi?

Comment: Because I want to do SPI wirelessly if it is possible. I know I could use a pi zero, or wires, but what I'd really like to do is have a pi hidden away in a cabinet, and a slim device hidden behind the display that does the SPI over the air.