# How can Rpi communicate with Arduino in RF (Radio Frequency), Say Using nRFL2401+?

Tags: pi-3, wireless, pi-4, arduino, communication

I need to transmit and receive data between Rpi and Arduino, in RF (Radio Frequency).

I must say I have next to zero experience in this field. So any help, papers, documentation, book or manual would be much appreciated.

Actually I don't have a clue where to start. I hope to get all necessary information including the following:

> (1) RF communication protocol, tutorials, libraries, and demo
>   programs,
>
> (2) RF modules to use for my RF project.

Comment: `certain RF modulation`  ... that means `specific RF modulation` ..... why did you not say which RF modulation you are talking about?

Comment: Hello @andromeda1912, Welcome and nice to meet you. Ah, let me see.  First of all, I like your question very much, because it is sort of brainstorming for innovative, IoT projects starting up, ideas on a broad area, yet narrowing down to RF, Rpi, Arduino. Usually I would suggest to zoom out to the "forest", then in to "trees", then in to the wood: "RF, Rpi, Arduino". I would suggest that we get started by reading a future proof, wide angle view white paper, . to continue, ...

Comment: Actually there are too many good white papers out there, so I usually first wiki and google, search keywords like "RF", "MCU", and the names of the big guys. My short list include the following, which I think should be a good read: "Connect Your MCU - Øivind Loe, Senior Product Manager – MCU and Sensors, Silicon Labs, 2020feb": https://www.silabs.com/whitepapers/connect-your-mcu. Happy reading, Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

***Question***

> How can Rpi talk to Arduino in RF?

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Answer***

*For poor IoT hobbyists like me, I would suggest to start with:*

> (1) BLE (2.4GHz),
>
> (2) NFC (13.56MHz), and
>
> (3) 5G (452.5 ~ 467.5MHz, 700MHz~ 2.2GHz)

Above three are wild choices.

For newbies, I would eliminate

(1) BLE, because RPi4B buster BLE still have teething problems,

(2) NFC, because it is only for short range (< 10cm),

(3) 5G (LTE-M), because it might also have teething problems, when finally coming to town, hopefully in 2020April.

So I think

> 2.4GHz modules such as nRF24L01+ seems to be the optimum choice for newbies.

---

[image: nrf24l01]

---

And for hobbyists, I would recommend the popular, but still cheap, US$1 module nRF24L01+.  You can find loads of Arduino tutorials on this cheap module. There is also a Rpi to Arduino tutorial (Ref 2, 3).

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***References***

(1) [Connect Your MCU - Øivind Loe, Senior Product Manager – MCU and Sensors, Silicon Labs， 2020feb](https://www.silabs.com/whitepapers/connect-your-mcu)

(2) [Rpi SPI nRF24L01+ 2.4GHz Transceiver Module Send Message to Arduino Problem (Q&A)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107608/rpi-spi-nrf24l01-2-4ghz-transceiver-module-send-message-to-arduino-problem)

(3) [Rpi SPI nRF24L01+ 2.4GHz Transceiver Module Send Message to Arduino Problem (Chat Record)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103645/discussion-on-question-by-stevencellist-rpi-spi-nrf24l01-2-4ghz-transceiver-mod)

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Appendices***

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Figures***

*Fig 1*

[image: fig 1]

---

*Fig 2*

[image: fig 2c]

---

*Fig 3*

[image: fig 3]

*/ to continue, ...*

---

*Fig 4*

[image: nrf24 4]

---

*Fig 5*

[image: nrf24 5]

---

*End of Answer*