# Dynamically setting address of HT12E

Tags: radio

I have a project where I need to send a wireless signal to one of several receivers to turn on an LED.

One transmitter, several (many) receivers, each with an LED.
The receivers need to have low power consumption.

**Transmitter side:**

- Raspberry pi
- HT12E encoder
- 433 mhz transmitter

**Receiver side:**

- 433 mhz receiver
- HT12D decoder

Each individual receiver would have a unique, fixed address.

I was hoping I could use the raspberry pi to dynamically set the address of the encoder to match the relevant receiver, but I cannot figure out if this is possible. The address of the HT12 is adjusted by connecting Ax pins to ground. Can I do this with

Is there a better alternative to this? Can I use the Raspberry to simulate the signal from the encoder?
The system must be possible because it is similar to [restaurant pagers](https://electronics.howstuffworks.com/everyday-tech/restaurant-pager.htm)

This is how I am envisioning it now. Am I understanding correct? Do the address on the transmitter side match with the address on the receiver side?

[image]

EDIT: Added sketch of wiring.

Comment: this one? https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/33021815597.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.909c5f42npmgPi&algo_pvid=db030d33-7868-41d9-9de6-f97914fcc0e9&algo_expid=db030d33-7868-41d9-9de6-f97914fcc0e9-1&btsid=0ab50f6215833190118896669e5de8&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

Comment: This encoder: https://electrosome.com/ht12e-encoder-ic-remote-control-systems/. Although it could be some other encoder/decoder pair. I am open for suggestions.

Comment: this datasheet? http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/57850.pdf

Comment: @tlfong01, your link is for the decoder and I want to dynamically address the encoder, but the principle is the same. Datasheet of the encoder: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1899539.pdf

Comment: I see.  I once played with RF12B 433MHz, which seems a bit out of date. In order not to lose face and damage my reputation, I switched to nRF12L01+ 2.4GHz: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108959/how-can-rpi-communicate-with-arduino-in-rf-radio-frequency.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "dynamically address the encoder". I think nRF24 is flexible enough to do what you want.   You might like to skim the following references to get a rough idea. I also played with IR transceiver.  I usually have two transceiver at both side, each with an Rpi, so I can experiment with different ideas: References: (1) "nRF24L01+ Q&A":
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107608/rpi-spi-nrf24l01-2-4ghz-transceiver-module-send-message-to-arduino-problem, to continue, ...

Comment: (2) "nRF24L01+ Chat Record":
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103645/discussion-on-question-by-stevencellist-rpi-spi-nrf24l01-2-4ghz-transceiver-mod

(3)  "nRF24L01+ Reading Log": 
https://penzu.com/p/e0ddab2a. Cheers.

Comment: I read your reference on restaurant pager and now understand your user requirement: https://electronics.howstuffworks.com/everyday-tech/restaurant-pager3.htm. Those pagers use microprocessors or mcu, but if you are producing small quantities or prototyping, then you can start with RpiZW.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I would prefer using a microprocessor or encoder/decoder pair and avoid the RpiZW on the receiver side because I need a high number of receivers.

Comment: I agree, if the quantity is large.  By the way, ESP8266 WiFi controller might be another thing beside microprocessor you might consider.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pull down resistor (270R-470R) for all A0 to A7 address points to earth. Then directly connect A0-A7 to GPIOs on RPi. Initialise these GPIOs to OUT and OFF, that will mean all address points run to earth and hence address of 00000000. Switch on respective GPIOs to required address. Voila.

Comment: Thanks, Pete. It was exactly something like this, I had imagined. Do you have a link to a pull down resistor I could use? What you are saying is that I connect each encoder leg to a GPIO via a resistor, is that right?