# NRF24L01 with USB-TTL converter

Tags: nrf24l01

Does anyone have experience with using NRF24L01 with USB-TTL [converter](https://fluxworkshop.com/products/beaa100021-usb-to-nrf24l01-interface-lc-blue)? (All my GPIO pins are already in use, that's why I need the USB converter).

I have a NRF24L01 + USB-TTL combo plugged into my PC and another combo plugged into the USB port of my RPi3b+.

I'm having trouble getting a connection over putty. My goal is to login to the RPi from my PC over long range serial connection

Found no guides to using the NRF with the USB-TTL converter. Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: (1) You might like to use a GPIO expander such as MCP23x17 to free up some of your GPIOs.  (2) You might find the following NRF24L01+ Q&A useful: (1) How can Rpi communicate with Arduino in RF Using nRFL2401+
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108959/how-can-rpi-communicate-with-arduino-in-rf-radio-frequency-say-using-nrfl2401/108961#108961

(2) Rpi SPI nRF24L01+ 2.4GHz Transceiver Module Send Message to Arduino Problem - Chat 
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103645/discussion-on-question-by-stevencellist-rpi-spi-nrf24l01-2-4ghz-transceiver-mod. / to continue, ...

Comment: (3) Rpi SPI nRF24L01+ 2.4GHz Transceiver Module Send Message to Arduino Problem - Q&A
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107608/rpi-spi-nrf24l01-2-4ghz-transceiver-module-send-message-to-arduino-problem

(4) Getting a NRF24L01 module running with Java Q&A
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111679/getting-a-nrf24l01-module-running-with-java/111726#111726. Cheers.

Comment: You might like to google some updated (2019 or later, must use version "+") NRF24L01+ tutorials. such as this one: 
(5) Wireless RF Communication using nRF24L01 Module Rpi - Abhiemanyu Pandit 2019aug01
https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/wireless-rf-communication-between-arduino-and-raspberry-pi-using-nrf24l01. This tutorial includes a Rpi python demo code, seems newbie friendly! :) Good luck and have a great 2021 new year project. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ask the vendor.

The NRF24L01 only supports a SPI interface.

There must be firmware on your linked module which is converting serial commands into SPI commands and vice versa.  The vendor needs to give you the details of that interface.

Comment: I forgot to mention my goal is to login to the RPi from the PC. Would I need to write a python script for this? Or shouldn't I be able to use Putty to make a serial connection between the two NRF modules?