# Pi4 GPIO Control with Java

Tags: pi-4, led, java, pi4j

I am basically trying to turn on a led by using pi4j library. My code is pretty simple:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    GpioController gpioController = GpioFactory.getInstance();
    GpioPinDigitalOutput pinOut = gpioController.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_17);
    pinOut.high();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    pinOut.low();
}
```

I am exporting the jar file from my computer, copying to my Raspberry Pi 4 than running in there.

To check if my led is not broken or GPIO is set, I've executed following Python scripts and I see my led works perfectly:

```
python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(17,True)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you get any errors?  My concern is that Pi 4 is not supported going by the list at https://pi4j.com/1.2/ Also check that the pin numbering https://pi4j.com/1.2/pin-numbering-scheme.html matches the BCM numbering.

Comment: @Andyroo I don't get any errors, I can even see the console writes on my pi. I also couldn't find anything regarding to pi4 on pi4j documentation but I didn't worry a lot since it didn't give me any errors...

Comment: As @andyroo has said. 1) the Pi4 is not supported. 2) you are using the wrong GPIO numbering scheme.

Comment: The Pi4 has GPIO located at different addresses and pull-ups are different, so the library will need to be modified.

Comment: Or you can try BlueJ, or what Pi Mag suggests. More details in the following Q&A (Appendix B of my answer) : https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111679/getting-a-nrf24l01-module-running-with-java. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed as mentioned in the comments, Pi4J is using a different pin numbering scheme. "Under the hood", WiringPi is used to control the GPIOs. This library uses a different numbering scheme. **This means BCM pin 17 you are using in Python is pin 0 in the WiringPi scheme.**

See below a full table with BCM, WiringPi, and physical pin numbering (see link 2 below).

[image: Raspberry Pi numbering scheme with BCM and WiringPi numbering]

Next to that, the internal wiring of the Raspberry Pi 4 is different compared to the previous ones, so you'll need to upgrade your WiringPi to the latest version 2.52 with:

```
$ gpio -v
gpio version: 2.50

$ cd /tmp
$ wget https://project-downloads.drogon.net/wiringpi-latest.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i wiringpi-latest.deb
$ gpio -v
gpio version: 2.52
```

As a side note: we are working on a new version of Pi4J which will make things easiers, but work-in-progress... ;-)

More info in my blog posts on:

1. [Using Pi4j (V1) on the Raspberry Pi 4](https://webtechie.be/post/2020-10-10-pi4j-on-raspberry-pi-4/)
2. [Raspberry Pi history, versions, pins and headers as a Java Maven library](https://webtechie.be/post/2019-11-13-raspberry-pi-history-versions-pins-headers-as-a-java-maven-library/)
3. [Oracle Java Magazine: Getting started with JavaFX on Raspberry Pi](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/getting-started-with-javafx-on-raspberry-pi)

Comment: I see there is a difference in pin numbering but when I change my code for GPIO_00 (Which is the WiringPI pin for GPIO_17) I get runtime error saying: Unable to open GPIO direction interface for pin[0]: No such file or directory.

Comment: Just an idea, can you try another pin? E.g. pin 40 = BCM 21 = WiringPi 29 as used in the example at https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/getting-started-with-javafx-on-raspberry-pi#anchor_5

Comment: Yes indeed, for some reason some pins are working and some are not. I am basically just brute-forcing to see which ones I can use. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough reputation to comment...

In the PI4J library, you use constants like "GPIO_16"...
However, these are not the GPIO pins that you find in the RPI documentation. They are the WiringPI pins.

A mapping is here: https://pinout.xyz/pinout/wiringpi