# What Java library to use for GPIO with raspberry pi 4b

Tags: pi-4, java

What Java library should I use to control raspberry pi 4b, Pi4J does not support rpi4. Wiringpi is deprecated. I tried searching for others b ut cannot find anything, how to control gpio with java in 2020?

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that diozero (documentation now at https://www.diozero.com/) works with all flavours of Raspberry Pi, from the armv6 based Pi Zero through to the latest Pi4 / Compute Module 4, as well as many other SBCs (tested on Odroid C2, Beaglebone Green/Black, TinkerBoard, NanoPi Neo/Duo2). Also works on both 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems (Raspberry Pi OS, Armbian and Ubuntu). Finally, it also works with Arduino devices using Firmata.

Answer (score 1):

Different possibilities...

- Pi4J V1 with and upgraded version of WiringPi (v2.52), see my answer on [Pi4 GPIO Control with Java](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/117513/pi4-gpio-control-with-java/117534#117534)
- Pi4J V2 which uses PiGpio instead of WiringPi, but is still a work-in-progress, see https://v2.pi4j.com/
- If you need limited GPIO functionality you can use terminal commands or even a Python script included in your project. All this is described in my book "[Getting Started with Java on the Raspberry Pi](https://webtechie.be/books/)" and all the examples are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/FDelporte/JavaOnRaspberryPi)
- I haven't used this myself yet, but https://diozero.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ seems to provide similar functionality as Pi4J

Comment: There is a new version V1.3 of Pi4J available which includes a script to update WiringPi to an "unofficial" fork which is fully Pi 4 compatible! See https://www.pi4j.com/1.3/dependency.html

Answer (score 0):

They have new version of Pi4J V.2 with Java 11, support RPI 4 B+. Pi4J V.2 had the first release in August 2021. So, go do it !

[Pi4J 2.0](https://pi4j.com/about/new-in-v2/)